# Update Existing Contact Image in Android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to update existing contact's image using below code :

```
builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
                builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", 
                        new String[]{String.valueOf(rawContactId), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE});
                builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, stream.toByteArray());
                ops.add(builder.build());

------


try {
        contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When contact have another images previously, then this code works fine. But when existing contact don't have any image, then this code not able to update that contact's image.

Please guide me , how to update an existing contact's (Contact which don't have any image previously) image.